# Выбор данных по заданному параметру в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Существует база данных в ней находится таблица **`wp_bp_xprofile_data`**. В этой таблице есть столбик со значениями

[image]

Нужно выбрать только те данные, в которых стоит значение **`id2`**.

[image]

Выбрать надо с помощью этого скрипта:

```
sql-driver-connection=jdbc\:mysql\://домен/Bukkit?user\=логин&пароль\=fun
sql-query=SELECT name FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE name\='<%value%>'
```

Знаю, что надо дописать тут

```
sql-query=SELECT name FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE name\='<%value%>'
```

Но как это сделать, никак не пойму, прошу помощи.

Comment: Сначала не мог понять, что по этим адресам скриншоты. Разве название таблицы сложнее написать, чем сделать скрин с названием?

Comment: Перепишите вопрос, пожалуйста, текстом. «… таблица `wp_bp_xprofile_data`, в этой таблице есть столбик `field_id` с целочисленными неуникальными значениями. Нужно выбрать только те данные, в которых стоит значение [*тут я не понял по каким критериям и что хотите выбирать, сами объясняйте*]»

Comment: Минусы любой поставить может.
Объясняю. Нужно выбрать из таблицы данных wp_bp_profile_data определенные данные(field_id) со значением 2. В строке value "любой текст"

Comment: Так. Ничего не понятно, еще раз. То, что надо выбрать — оно, вообще-то, должно быть неизвестно, иначе выбирать это неинтересно. И причем тут value? (И что это вообще такое, столбец?)

Если надо выбрать все значения в столбце `value`, для рядов, где значение `field_id` равно 2, то, например, так: `SELECT value FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 2`.

Comment: @Никита Аристархов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора. Чтобы вставить картинку используйте соответствующую кнопку редактора.

Comment: В таблице БД (wp_bp_xprofile_data) нужно выбрать только те значения которые равняются field_id 2

Comment: Запрос `SELECT name FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE name='...'` не несет практического смысла, т.к. выбирается известное значение для `name`. Это типа как «вывести имена всех людей, которых зовут Вася».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 2`

Если нужны не все столбцы, а один (или несколько, но не все) — вместо «`*`» подставить их имена, через запятую. Например: `SELECT value FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 2`

Условия во `WHERE` объединяются через `AND`. Если нужно выбрать значение value с field_id = 2 для конкретного пользователя, то `SELECT * FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 2 AND user_id = 123`.

(`sql-driver-connection=... sql-query=` везде пропущено для удобства чтения)

Answer (score 1):

Лол. Щито? Я твоё речь не понимат! Что за скрипт у Вас для выбора я не знаю. Операция выбора данных при неком условии из бд очень проста. Например, мне нужно вывести все логины моих пользователей, если они выбрали из городов Moscow.

```
include ("bd.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE pole='Moscow'",$db); //извлекаем логин и идентификатор пользователей 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
//выводим их в цикле 
printf("<a    href='page.php?id=%s'>%s</a><br>",$myrow['id'],$myrow['login']);
}
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: Нужно именно так, как на php, я знаю.

    sql-driver-connection=jdbc:mysql://домен/Bukkit?user=логин&пароль=fun
    sql-query=SELECT name FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE name='<%value%>'

Comment: а что такое name?